# working with instance attributes and methods

Tags: python

How do I adapt, the `checkLength()` method, to accept any instance attributes I pass to it? For example in this context, I can check either first or last, without hardcoding it inside the checkLength() method?

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
class Name:
  def __init__(self, f, l):
    self.first = f
    self.last = l

  def checkLength(self):
    if type(self.first) == str:
      return len(self.first)
    else:
      return False

myName = Name('Sir', 'Mixalot') 
print(myName.checkLength())
```

I have tried the following combinations:

```
  def checkLength(self, last):
    if type(self.last) == str:
      return len(self.last)
    else:
      return False

print(myName.checkLength(last))
```

```
  def checkLength(self.last):
    if type(self.last) == str:
      return len(self.last)
    else:
      return False

print(myBody.checkLength(self.last))
```

Update - trying to use getattr

```
  def __init__(self, f, l):
    self.first = f
    self.last = l

  def checkLength(self, attr):
    if type(getattr(self, attr)) == str:
      return len(getattr(self, attr))
    else:
      return False

myName = Name('Sir', 'Mixalot') 
print(myName.checkLength(self, "last"))
```

error =

`````
NameError: name 'self' is not defined````
`````

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what is that you want to achieve with the checkLength function ? As in what is the desired use of this function ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `len` function directly? For example: `print(len(myName.last))` Or, if you need a version of `len` which checks the type first, you can write this function (`typeSafeLen`) independently of your class.

Comment: Your question is not clear. According to what are you going to choose between checking the `len` of `f` or `l`?

Comment: Side-note: For type-checking, you want either `if isinstance(self.first, str):` (allows subclasses) or `if type(self.first) is str:` (strict test for that exact class). Don't use `== str`; the `str` class is a singleton, and if you want strict checking, use `is` for identity testing, not `==` (for loose value equality testing).

Comment: It should be `print(myName.checkLength("last"))`

Comment: @ShadowRanger great explanation, thank you, that would have taken me while to gain that knowledge. Thank you for helping a newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `getattr(object, name[, default])`. For example:

```
class Name:
  def __init__(self, f, l):
    self.first = f
    self.last = l

  def checkLength(self, attr):
    if type(getattr(self, attr)) == str:
      return len(getattr(self, attr))
    else:
      return False

myName = Name('Sir', 'Mixalot') 
print(myName.checkLength("first"))
```

> 3

But you should also add some error handling when that attribute is missing.

Comment: thank you for your kind response, I am not familiar with getattr, your suggestion is most helpful. I updated my code in the original post. I am still struggling with this solution as I get a error message ```print(myBody.checkLength(self, last)). NameError: name 'self' is not defined```

Comment: @dimButTries I thinks you forgot to put all that in the class.